# BIRT viewer not working in Internet Explorer on some machines

Tags: internet-explorer, tomcat, tomcat6, birt, tomcat8

I developed a report with BIRT Designer 4.5.0. When I deploy in BIRT viewer webapp (which is provided by BIRT itself) on a Tomcat 6 or 8, report works in any machine and browsers.

But there is a machine where it does not render when opened by Internet Explorer. It just drows a little grey rectangle in the top left corner of the page.

Answer (score 1):

After many attempts I succeded, doing this in Internet Explorer: options menu > Internet Options > Security tab > Trusted sites > Sites > write the domain where report is hosted > Add > Close > OK.